# Reading from a file: complex number with small imaginary part

Tags: matrix, import, complex

I'm trying to read a matrix from the next file:

```
1+1e-18i 24
42 23.43e-23i
```

using `u=Import["file.dat","Table"];` and then find, for example, the trace: `Tr[u]` but this give me `1+1e-23i + 1+23.43e-23i`. Also, `Chop` don't work.

How obtain the correct representation of the matrix in the file?

Comment: IIRC, `ReadList` will parse the numbers correctly, though I don't know if it will read in the correct format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all parts of your file are recognized as numeric data during the `Import`.

```
u = Import["file.dat"]

Head /@ Flatten[u]
```

$\ $ `{String, Integer, Integer, String}`

You can convert it for example with

```
SetAttributes[stringToNumber, Listable];
stringToNumber[s_String] := ToExpression[StringReplace[s, {"e" -> " 10^", "i" -> " I"}]];
stringToNumber[s_] := s;

u2 = stringToNumber@u
```

$\ $ `{{1 + I/1000000000000000000, 24}, {42, 0. + 2.343*10^-22 I}}`

Now

```
Chop[N@u2]
```

$\ $ `{{1., 24.}, {42., 0}}`

Answer (score 7):

One possibility: try this (you can use Import on your file instead):

```
lines = ImportString[
  "1+1e-18i 24
   42 23.43e-23i",
"Lines"]
```

Then:

```
result = Map[StringSplit, lines]
```

And:

```
Map[Interpreter["ComplexNumber"], result, {2}]
```

This gives:

```
 {{1.` + 1.`*^-18 I, 24}, {42, 0.` + 2.343`*^-22 I}}
```

Comment: On can use `Map[Interpreter["ComplexNumber"], u, {2}]` for `u = Import["file.dat"]`, if the file is formated as shown in the question.

Comment: I don't have the built in function Interpreter... I'm using Mathematica 9.