# Import imaginary numbers

Tags: import, data

I'm trying to import a matrix data which contains complex numbers, and uses "i" as the imaginary number. Because Mathematica uses "I" for the imaginary number, it doesn't read my data as complex numbers. I've tried StringReplace to change the i to I but doesn't work.

For reference, im using : Import["file.txt", "Table"], to import my data.

Comment: Hello Gianni, I don't suppose you can share your matrix data, or at least a few lines of it?

Comment: Yes, no problem. https://drive.google.com/file/d/16y3rd-AU-Bb14SlEpinWe5iNS2POIOjL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89938/75628) provides a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank's! That solved my problem.